# Parenthesis in Python Yield statement

Tags: python, css, yield

Im trying to set up a table to display some information on a webpage using yield.  I cant get around the parenthesis for grid container so its not returning the whole code.  Any way around this using yield?  Or do i need another method altogether?

`yield " <div class="grid-container"> ".encode('utf-8')`

I was using a `<table>` but I didnt like the formatting, so I wanted to try grid-container.  Its a webscraper using BeautifulSoup.  Here is some of the information going to the table

```
            yield "<div class="grid-container">".encode('utf-8')
            for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':"col-md-10"}):
                yield "<tr>".encode('utf-8')
                for name in div.findAll('div', attrs={'name':"label-Address"}):
                     yield "<td>{}</td>".format(name.text).encode('utf-8')
                yield "</tr>".encode('utf-8')
                yield "<tr>".encode('utf-8')
                for name in div.findAll('div', attrs={'name':"label-ScheduledDate"}):
                     yield "<td>{}</td>".format(name.text).encode('utf-8')
                yield "</tr>".encode('utf-8')
                yield "<tr>".encode('utf-8')
                for name in div.findAll('div', attrs={'name':"label-CaseNumber"}):
                     yield "<th>{}</th>".format(name.text).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: There is a complete lack of context to the question, why the isolated `yield` statement? What framework is this? Which parenthesis? What is the "whole code"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a syntax error as you are using quotes twice, you should correct it like this:

```
yield " <div class='grid-container'> ".encode('utf-8')
```